# Simple jquery counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hi all i have got this really simple jquery counter

```
    var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
     alert('done');
    }
    count--;
}, 1000);
```

How can i make it reset after it gets to 0 instead of going into minus???? so it keep iterating.

http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/mSQdp/

any help

Answer (score 3):

To reset and repeat, put `count = 11;` after the `alert('done');`.

To stop, put `clearInterval(countdown);` after the `alert('done');`.

Comment: Delan -- the `clearInterval` does not have to be `after the alert(...`

Comment: I know. It was merely a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    count--;    
    if (count == 0) {
      count = 10;
    }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 10,
    countdown = setInterval(function () {
        $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
        if (count == 0) {
            count = 11; //since it will be reduced right after this
            //clearInterval(countdown); <-- use this if you want to stop 
            alert('done');
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: No, he wants it to start counting from 10 again, not stop.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
if (count == 0)
  count = 11
```

You might also want to look at the [jQuery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Comment: The only caveat with this is that immediately after, the `count--;` will make the count effectively 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if (count == 0) {     
    alert('done');    
    count = 11;
}
...
```

Comment: `count` needs to be set to 11, not 10, because of the `count--` immediately afterwards.